# can't concat a variable with a string using eval?

Tags: javascript, dom, eval

```
for (let i=0;i<11;i++){
 const i=1
  const  q1="selectedQuestion"
  const  q2="selectedAnswer"
  const  q3="selectedArrow"
  const ans_q1="que"+i
  const ans_q2="ans"+i
  const ans_q3 ="arrow"+i
eval("let "+q1+i+"="+"document.getElementById"+`(${ans_q1})`);
eval("let "+q2+i+"="+"document.getElementById"+`(${ans_q2})`);
eval("let "+q3+i+"="+"document.getElementById"+`(${ans_q3})`);
const final_q1=q1+i
const final_q2=q2+i
const final_q3=q3+i

final_q1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (final_q2.classList.contains("hidden")) {
        final_q2.classList.remove("hidden")
        final_q3.innerText = "<"
    } else {
        final_q2.classList.add("hidden")
        final_q3.innerText = ">"
    }
})

}
```

I tried everything , but this code doesn't work I wanted to  manually assign variable name ,so I don't have to hardcode it.

Comment: [let and const declarations within the evaluated string are always scoped to that script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Why are you mixing string concatenation and template strings in the same expression!?

Comment: There's no point in using unique names for the variables anyway — `let` variables are scoped to the iteration of the `for` loop so using the same name in each loop is fine (which removes the need for variables variables in the first place).

Comment: @Quentin ,thx very ignorant mistake